# How to send push notification to all android and ios devices at once in react native using expo?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I've found a way to send push notification to a single device using expo but dont know how to send to all devices

Answer (score 1):

Looks like expo can send only to a specific user(token). Why don't you try [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)? It is free, easy to integrate and you have the possibility to send to either one specific device or to all the registered devices.

Comment: do i have to eject the project or can i use it with expo

Comment: Looks like you don't have to. https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/